# Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

When I try to run `npm run build` can't build the code or start the React app. Here is the error I get:

```
> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at /Users/clare/flights-gui/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:918
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/clare/flights-gui/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:5:584)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! flights-gui@1.0.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the flights-gui@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/clare/.npm/_logs/2021-03-17T20_18_10_288Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Could you provide more info on what could be causing it? It's hard to tell what the issue is with this error message only. Do you have any custom webpack config in your `next.config.js`?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. No clue from `npm run build --debug`. No idea how to solve this.